# Stable Marriage algorithm java code

Tags: java, list, stable-marriage

I need to implement makeMatches method in stable marriage class. 
Code needs to follow this algorithm:

```
set each person to be free;
while (some man m with a nonempty preference list is free) {
    w = first woman on m's list;
    if (some man p is engaged to w) {
        set p to be free
    }
    set m and w to be engaged to each other
    for (each successor q of m on w's list) {
        delete w from q's preference list
        delete q from w's preference list
    }
}
```

However I can not find my error.  The program makes couples depend on their first choices but after that doesn't continue and set couples.
Could you look at my code and tell me what is wrong with it?

Person.java is provided from instructor:

```
   import java.util.*;

    public class Person {
        public static final int NOBODY = -1;

    private String name;
    private List<Integer> preferences;
    private List<Integer> oldPreferences;
    private int partner;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        preferences = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        oldPreferences = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        erasePartner();
    }

    public void erasePartner() {
        partner = NOBODY;
    }

    public boolean hasPartner() {
        return partner != NOBODY;
    }

    public int getPartner() {
        return partner;
    }

    public void setPartner(int partner) {
        this.partner = partner;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean hasChoices() {
        return !preferences.isEmpty();
    }

    public int getFirstChoice() {
        return preferences.get(0);
    }

    public void addChoice(int person) {
        preferences.add(person);
        oldPreferences.add(person);
    }

    public List<Integer> getChoices() {
        return preferences;
    }

    public int getPartnerRank() {
        return oldPreferences.indexOf(partner) + 1;
    }
}
```

And StablaMarriage.java is the one I need to implement code in.

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;

  public class StableMarriage {
      public static final String LIST_END = "END";

      public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the input file? ");
        String fileName = console.nextLine();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        System.out.println();

        List<Person> men = readHalf(input);
        List<Person> women = readHalf(input);

        makeMatches(men, women);
        writeList(men, women, "Matches for men");
        writeList(women, men, "Matches for women");
    }

    public static Person readPerson(String line) {
        int index = line.indexOf(":");
        Person result = new Person(line.substring(0, index));
        Scanner data = new Scanner(line.substring(index + 1));
        while (data.hasNextInt()) {
            result.addChoice(data.nextInt());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static List<Person> readHalf(Scanner input) {
        List<Person> result = new ArrayList<Person>();
        String line = input.nextLine();
        while (!line.equals(LIST_END)) {
            result.add(readPerson(line));
            line = input.nextLine();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void makeMatches(List<Person> list1, List<Person> list2) {

      for (Person eachMan :  list1){
         eachMan.setPartner(-1);
     }
     for (Person eachWoman : list2){
         eachWoman.setPartner(-1);
     }

    for (Person man : list1){
        for (Person woman : list2){
        while (man.hasChoices() && !man.hasPartner()){
            int choosenWoman = man.getFirstChoice(); 
            for (Person p : list1){
                if (p.getPartner()== choosenWoman){
                     p.setPartner(-1);
                }
            }
            man.setPartner(choosenWoman);
            list2.get(choosenWoman).setPartner(list1.indexOf(man));

           List manList= man.getChoices();
            List womanList = woman.getChoices();
            for (int q= womanList.size()-1; q>=0; q--){
                if(q>womanList.indexOf(list1.indexOf(man)))
                    manList.remove(manList.indexOf(man.getFirstChoice()));
                     womanList.remove(q);


                 }  

        }
        }
    }
    }

    public static void writeList(List<Person> list1,  List<Person> list2,
                                 String title) {
        System.out.println(title);
        System.out.println("Name           Choice  Partner");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (Person p : list1) {
            System.out.printf("%-15s", p.getName());
            if (!p.hasPartner()) {
                System.out.println("  --    nobody");
            } else {
                int rank = p.getPartnerRank();
                sum += rank;
                count++;
                System.out.printf("%4d    %s\n", rank,
                                  list2.get(p.getPartner()).getName());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Mean choice = " + (double) sum / count);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: The pseudocode never loops on the women list, while your implementation does.

Comment: for (each successor q of m on w's list) {
For that part of the pseudocode I need to loop on women list. Didn't I ?

Comment: nope. `w` is the "first woman on m's list", so "w's list" is a list of men (the men `w` likes). Anyway, it's nor the list of all the men neither the list of all the women.